# GWT / SmartGWT / cross site relative paths issue

Tags: path, linker, smartgwt, skin, cross-site

I am struggling with following issue described in short: Loading module cross site results in no skin due to wrong image paths etc.

What am I trying: I am trying to provide an HTML code snippet which can be embedded in publisher websites and which is loading one of my SmartWGT modules. Loading the JavaScript works fine after using GWT linker "xs" as well as my own CSS which is linked in *.gwt.xml but the SmartGWT skin is missing and my images. When I check the source for skin images etc. this points to host of publisher website instead my host.

Here my HTML snippet for embedding:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.xanaroo.de/xanaroo/org.xanaroo.XanarooLite/org.xanaroo.XanarooLite.nocache.js"></script>
    <div id="xanaroo_lite"></div>
```

Please can somebody tell me how this will work as I don't know how to proceed. GWT linker "xsiframe" does not work due to issues with SmartGWT JavaScript files during compilation. So, there must be some other solution!? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `setSkinDir` to indicate another host than the one where your module is running. You can have a look to this old [post](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=3511&highlight=setskindir)